# Как получить параметры картинки до её загрузки?

Tags: javascript, html

Возможно ли как-то получить высоту и ширину картинки до её загрузки(с сервера на клиент), но без использования PHP и прочего back-end?

Comment: блин.. ну это как у святого духа спросить.... как можно узнать параметры того.. что ты еще не получил.. и не измеряя ее там где она находится?

Comment: и загрузки через браузер на сервер или из сервера в браузер?

Comment: из сервера в браузер

Comment: тогда только предварительно на бэкенде смотреть свойства... или загружать его но не отображать..., проверять его и  потом только применять какие-то действия

Answer (score 2):

Можешь эмулировать загрузку картинки, а потом получать ширину и высоту:

```js
function getImgSize(imgSrc) {
  var newImg = new Image();

  newImg.onload = function() {
    var height = newImg.height;
    var width = newImg.width;
    console.log('Ширина:' + width + ' Высота:' + height);
  }

  newImg.src = imgSrc;
}

getImgSize('https://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/daily/science/2017/04/10/10-nature-outdoors.w710.h473.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, это как с *бубном танцевать и ждать дождя*. Вот как вы себе представляете, получение размеров фото до его загрузки?
Но все же могу предложить пару вариантов:

1. Вы можете указать на сайте где вы грузите картинку, что размеры должны быть такими-то например **512х512**;
2. Создать что-то вроде буфера, где и конкретно измерять размер фото а после сверять их с вашими **данными**;

Каким образом вы собираетесь это сделать, ещё и без языков? Интересно какое у вас мнение, на этот повод? А мы уже и поможем вам, додумать до конца. ;)

P.s. Вы может хотите как на сайтах вроде Вконтакте или Ютуб, где вам пишут что - изображение не подходит?

Comment: Нет, я прелоадер решил сделать. Хотел, чтоб было удобнее, сделать возможно автоматически выставлять размер блока перед загрузкой картинки. Я в принципе понимал, что это маловероятно, однако надежда на чудо была. Что ж, похоже, чуда не будет((

Comment: Миш, ну как ты это собирался чудить?)
Пускай грузится как я писал в буфер, а там уже делать с картинкой что угодно. Может и реально как ты говоришь сделать, но ты столько нервов и времени потратишь, что оно тебе и не нужно будет. Кроме бэкенда и тд. Ничего придумать не могу, извиняй)